# How to not pass unchecked checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, form-for

In case of form_for i don't want to pass the unchecked checkbox to controller. How to do that?

```
<%= f.checkbox :question_id %>
```

The above code will send both checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Look into check_box_tag. It builds a much simpler checkbox. checkbox uses a hidden field to ensure that a neutral value comes back when the box is unchecked. This is so that when you are updating model attributes, you explicitly set booleans to false instead of not changing them. Checkout this guide on using [FormHelper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) effectively.

and the documentation for [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Comment: I need to use check_box only, not check_box_tag

Comment: May I ask why you can't use check_box_tag? You should put restrictions on the solution space in your original question.

Comment: I cant use check_box_tag because i am using nested form and i dont want to access params[:question_id] in my controller, instead i want everything bound to the form object.